# External css file half works in html

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: lato;
    src: url(../rsrc/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: audrey;
    src: url(../rsrc/fonts/Audrey-Normal.otf);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 'head content foot';
}

.head {
    grid-area: head;
}


.barra1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.g2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.g2 img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.g3 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    border-color: red;
}

.e1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-color: orange;
}

.e1 a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-color: yellow;
}

.e1 a:hover {
    background-color: #7a7a7a;
    color: #fafafa;
}

.e1 a:active {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.barra2 {
    font-family: audrey;
    text-align: center;
}

.barra3 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
}

li.e3 {
    display: inline-block;
}

li.e3 a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: lato;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li.e3 a:hover {
    background-color: #7a7a7a;
    color: #fafafa;
}

.e3 a:active {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    color: #ffffff;
}


.barra4 {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.e4 {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 6px;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: lato;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.e4:hover {
    background-color: #7a7a7a;
    color: #fafafa;
}

.e4:active {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    color: #ffffff;
}


.content {
    grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css">
    <!----
    <style>
        .barra4 {
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .e4 {
            color: #ffffff;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 6px 6px;
            text-decoration-line: none;
            font-family: lato;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .e4:hover {
            background-color: #7a7a7a;
            color: #fafafa;
        }

        .e4:active {
            background-color: #1e1e1e;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <!---->

</head>
<body style="margin:0">
    <!--foot--><div class="barra4">
        <a href="ej/1.jpg" class="e4">Políticas y aviso legal</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The html file is called: C:\Users\silve\source\repos\TTWeb\html\foot.html
The css file is called: C:\Users\silve\source\repos\TTWeb\css\estilo.css
Both are in UTF-8 (not BOM or something else)

My problem is that when I give the style via internal css (inside  tag in foot.html as it is inside a comment) works no problem and the result is exactly how I want. But when I use the external css file (estilo.css) (style for foot is at the end) it doesn't apply completely. Background is right but link not, for example.

The same problem is also in other html files I have.
I have no idea why it doesn't work and no clue found on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was probably corrupt. I had it solved by CREATING NEW FILE AND COPYING ALL THE CONTENT. And fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Internal style tag and external files are prioritized differently: Based on its priority level, the internal style is higher, so it will overwrite the external styles.

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/

Try to figure out what properties are being overwritten and adjust accordingly, i.e. with important! (if nothing else works).

Comment: Thank you for answerig, but I don't think that is the case. As you can see there's really no internal or in-line style.

Futhermore, I fixed a little bit the css code and now there is just no format in the html page. It seems like it just can't import de css style, but I can't find any problems with that.

Comment: I did not mean the inline style, but the <style> in your index.html. It is ranked higher than an external file reference via <link>. That is why the properties are applied differently. If you think that you cannot import your css, check out the network tab in the developer tools of your browser - should it be the case, you will get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Any one should be applied either Internal css or External Style sheet.

Refer the following link for more info:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Also check if u have attempted any duplicate class or id.